# Gmail onEdit Apps Script,

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Is there an EVENT indicating that the message has been opened for editing in gmail? onEdit ?
I need to call a function that will run when the message is in edit mode.

Comment: In Gmail add-ons, there is a trigger when a user [opens a Gmail message](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/gmail-addons#contextualtrigger), and another one when a user is [composing new messages or replying to existing ones](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/gmail-addons#composetrigger). If you're not using add-ons, though, there's nothing available for you. If you need more details about this, I'd suggest you to edit your question and provide more information about your current situation and purpose.

Comment: I write now to maniffers file: "composeTrigger": {
        "selectActions": [
          {
            "text": "Add images to email",
            "runFunction": "loadAddOn"
          }
        ],
        "draftAccess": "METADATA",
        "selectActions": [
    {
      "runFunction": "loadAddOn"
    }
  ]
But dont run loadAddOn finction when I edit or create new message

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that this can be troubleshot?

Comment: its work. 
I have not noticed. Now an icon appears in the message editor. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Gmail add-on, you can trigger a function when the user is composing new messages or replying to existing ones: [ComposeTrigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/gmail-addons#composetrigger).

#### Reference:

- [Extending the compose UI with compose actions](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui)